# Generic ObjectCache with Expiration

Tags: c#, thread-safety, cache

I sometimes need an object that caches some data but only for the specified amount of time. So I created a class that should handle this. The main goal was to make it generic unlike the `MemoryCache` and be a single object cache and not a general all-pupose cache.

### `ObjectCache`

```
public class ObjectCache<T>
{
    private readonly object _valueExpiredMutex = new object();

    private T _value;

    public ObjectCache(TimeSpan expiration)
    {
        Expiration = expiration;
    }

    public EventHandler<ObjectCacheEventArgs<T>> ValueExpired { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Expiration { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; internal set; }

    public bool IsExpired
    {
        get { return !LastUpdate.HasValue || DateTime.Now - LastUpdate.Value > Expiration; }
    }

    public T GetValue()
    {
        if (!IsExpired)
        {
            return _value;
        }

        lock (_valueExpiredMutex)
        {
            _value = OnValueExpired();
            LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        return _value;
    }

    private T OnValueExpired()
    {
        if (ValueExpired == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ValueExpired event handler not set.");
        }

        var e = new ObjectCacheEventArgs<T>();
        ValueExpired(this, e);
        return e.Value;
    }
}
```

- `LastUpdate` has an `internal` setter so that I can set it in tests
- I tried to implement it to be thread-safe but I'm not sure if I did it correctly with only one *mutex* for getting a new value.
- Any kind of feedback is welcome ;-)

### `EventArgs`

```
public class ObjectCacheEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

### `Test`

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestObjectCache()
{
    var number = 1;

    var objectCache = new ObjectCache<int>(
        new TimeSpan(hours: 0, minutes: 21, seconds: 0));
    objectCache.ValueExpired += (sender, e) =>
    {
        e.Value = number++;
    };
            
    Assert.IsTrue(objectCache.IsExpired);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, objectCache.GetValue());
    Assert.IsFalse(objectCache.IsExpired);

    objectCache.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
    Assert.IsTrue(objectCache.IsExpired);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, objectCache.GetValue());
}
```

Comment: You probably saw my comment to Heslacher but you really should replace internal timings using `DateTime.Now` with `DateTime.UtcNow`, which is not only faster but also not prone to unexpected behavior during time zone transitions.

Comment: @RickDavin oops, right, yes, I'll implement this change too ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO this a strange aproach. One needs to first call `GetValue()` to be able to set a value by using an eventhandler. I would expect from such an `ObjectCache` to provide a constructor which takes a value as parameter too.

In addition I would add a property to `ObjectCacheEventArgs<T>` signaling a state, for instance an enum having the members `ChangeValue`, `KeepAlive` and `SkipValue` to be set by the handler of the event.
If this value is e.g set to `ChangeValue` then the `_value` should be changed. If it is set to `KeepAlive` the `LastUpdate` should be set to `DateTime.Now`. And for `SkipValue` you would need to add another var indicating that the value is skipped and set `_value` to `default(T)`.

It isn't obvious from a caller side of view that you have to add an eventhandler for that event. IMO this is a bad sign which one would maybe notice first at running the code. Such behaviour shouldn't be wanted and isn't expected. If one does not add an eventhandler he expects that he just don't get notified if this event happens.

Comment: I'd suggest that `LastUpdate` be set to `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`.  All internal time keeping should be Utc.

Comment: The idea is to let the event handler retrieve the value (usualy from an expensive database call) and use it for some time. If if force the user to set an initial value via the constructor he would need to retrieve the value twice, once for the constructor and the second time in the event handler. But I think I will redesign it so the constructor at least requires a `Fun<state, T>` method instead of an event. Then it shouldn't be easier to use it. Thank for your thougts ;-)

Comment: What would you say if I changed the constructor to take this delegate as a second parameter? `public delegate bool UpdateObjectCacheValue<T>(out T newValue);` ;-)

Comment: Looks fine to me. You could also just add it as an overloaded constructor so you won't break existing usage and refactor these later.

Comment: @Heslacher fortunately it's brand new and only one test application uses it so far so I'll get rid of the old construtor right away.